# Is self-publishing a good option?

Tags: self-publishing

Is the self publishing route one that is considered acceptable these days? Specifically, I am writing short stories, and there is no real chance of getting a publisher to look at short stories without some previous history.

Additionally, I don't expect to make enough money to justify a publisher, or even my time in trying to find one - I expect to make something, but not a great deal.  So self-publishing seems to make sense, to get some of my work out there, and see whether anyone likes it.

For this sort if work, is self-publishing a good route, a sensible route?

Comment: >is considered acceptable these days? - Define "acceptable", "considered" and why does it matter. You don't need someone's permission. Publish!

Comment: related: [pros and cons of different styles of publishing](http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/3612/pros-and-cons-of-different-styles-of-publishing)

Comment: "Acceptable" == better than vanity publishing. I actually do want people to take my work seriously. @Stadnback - thank yo ufor that link - I did search self-publishing questions before posting, but didn't seee this for some reason.

Comment: I'm closing this because it's vague. If it can be edited to ask a more specific question, we'll consider reopening. (If you simply want to know the pros and cons of self-publishing, the question Standback linked to covers that well - [this answer](http://writers.stackexchange.com/a/3613/26) in particular.)

Comment: I tried hard to be specific, for short stories, with little change of making much money. But the other links should help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how short you're talking, and whether you're talking about print or electronic, Amazon is explicitly pushing short/medium stories at present through their [Kindle Singles](http://www.amazon.com/b?ie=UTF8&node=2486013011) program, and a scan through the published works ranges from unknowns to Stephen King. I can't speak from personal experience, but it seems like it's a reasonable approach.